# Inject application properties without Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, annotations, spring-annotations

I would like a simple, preferably annotation-based way to inject external properties into a java program, without using the spring framework (`org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;`)

SomeClass.java

```
@Value("${some.property.name}")
private String somePropertyName;
```

application.yml

```
some:
  property:
    name: someValue
```

Is there a recommended way to do this in the standard library?

Comment: No, which is why Spring's functionality exists.

Comment: Since I wanted a non-spring answer, I shouldn't have included `spring`-* tags

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I ended up using [apache commons configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/):

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

src/.../PropertiesLoader.java

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
config.load(PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
config.getInt("someKey");
```

/src/main/resources/application.properties

```
someKey: 2
```

I did not want to turn my library into a Spring application (I wanted `@Value` annotations, but no application context + `@Component`, extra beans, extra Spring ecosystem/baggage which doesn't make sense in my project).

Comment: Thank you answering your question. I know this is a bad comment, but it's rare for people to come back and help others that may have the same problems. So thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you used this to read "application.yml" (emphasis on yml), OR you used this library and (reverted back) to read application.properties file?

Comment: I probably read from application.properties using this library, I don't think yml vs properties mattered to me at the time, but I don't remember.

Comment: Ok.  Yeah, I like the syntax of application.yml, but the spring-baggage is too much to bear for just that component.  @AnnotationEasyPeezey.

Comment: I'm surprised that this is the accepted answer with that many upvotes. The original question seemed to be asking for a pure JSR-330 way to achieve what `@Value` does in Spring, e.g. something like `@Inject @Named("some.property.name")
private String somePropertyName;` (which AFAIK is not actually supported by any of the frameworks that implement JSR-330). Also, the accepted answer is not annotation-based and, moreover, does not even use dependency injection at all. In my mind, this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Where does the question ask about pure JSR-330, or that annotations are a hard requirement?

Answer (score 12):

Define application properties here **/src/main/resources/application.properties**

**Define PropertiesLoader class**

```
public class PropertiesLoader {

    public static Properties loadProperties() throws IOException {
        Properties configuration = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = PropertiesLoader.class
          .getClassLoader()
          .getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
        configuration.load(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        return configuration;
    }
}
```

Inject property value in the required class like below,

```
    Properties conf = PropertiesLoader.loadProperties();
    String property = conf.getProperty(key);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! This code works pretty well. Why including a whole library if you can accomplish it with 10 lines of self written code.

Comment: OP asks for yaml approach. This solution doesn't work for YAML files.

Comment: This class could benefit by using a singleton so it doesn't actually load every time it's called.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this answer on google, yet i'm not satisfied.

In the end I created Environment class that uses both application properties from @Stone answer and hardcoded env variables. But Im still looking for better options, since I cannot modify ENV_VARIABLE name inside application.propeties, which is what I originally wanted.

```
public class EnvironmentPlainJava {

    public int httpsPort() {
        return Integer.parseInt(PropertiesLoader.loadProperties().getProperty("https.port"));
    }

    public String keyStorePath() {
        return System.getenv("KEY_STORE_PATH");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here is an idiomatic Kotlin version of the @Stone code (using `ClassPathResource` Spring utility class - doesn't require running Spring!):

```
fun loadProperties(properties: String = "application.properties"): Properties =
    ClassPathResource(properties).inputStream.use { inputStream ->
        Properties().also {
            it.load(inputStream)
        }
    }
```