# Reading property from application.properties not working in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to get this **@Value** running in an @Embeddable pojo class, but the value ist always false. All application.properties files are filled correctly. Is it maybe just not possible, because it's no srvice/ controller/ configuration?

```
@Embeddable
  public class WebDestination implements Serializable {
    
       @Value("${property.example}")
       private boolean example;


       public boolean isExample() {
            return example;
       }

       public void setExample(boolean example) {
           this.example= example;
       }
}
```

Comment: You can do it without Spring if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835785/inject-application-properties-without-spring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only inject property value using `@Value("${property.example}")` in components that are managed by Spring container (classes that are annotated with `@Service`, `@Controller`, `@Component`, `@Configuration`  and ...), you can't use it anywhere else.