# read ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE from application-env.yml in plain java

Tags: java, properties, environment-variables, javalin

I have a simple java web service that uses javalin framework. I want to deploy it in multiple environments, so the env variables are different for each deployment.

I basically want to read

application-env.yml

```
keystore:
  path: ${KEY_STORE_PATH}
  password: ${KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}
```

from application-env.yml **without** using Spring.

And then use them in java.

```
Properties properties = PropertiesLoader.loadProperties();
System.out.println(properties.getProperty("keystore.password"));
// ${KEY_STORE_PASSWORD} 
System.out.println(System.getenv("KEY_STORE_PASSWORD"));
// hunter2
```

How do I get hunter2 from properties?

EDIT:

i didnt get what I wanted, ended up doing this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73539823/2948875

Comment: Make it `.properties` and don't require further libs (java.util.Properties)

Comment: ```Properties properties = new Properties();
   String property = properties.getProperty("keystore.password");
   logger.info("property: {}", property);
```
> property: null

Comment: Properties.load(...)

Comment: then its just what I said in the post: ${KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}. But in cmd:

```> echo %KEY_STORE_PASSWORD%
> hunter2```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like SnakeYAML, ie https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml

Comment: I dont think it will work with env variables?

Comment: You have a file called env - they aren't actually env variables.